# How to debug code in aspects files (*.aj) with IDE?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, ide, aspectj, spring-roo

I have application created with Spring Roo. 
Roo project use plain java code and AspectJ's inter-type declaration aspects in *.aj files.

```
roo> project --topLevelPackage com.aspectj.rocks
roo> jpa setup --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY --provider HIBERNATE
roo> entity jpa --class ~.Hello
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/aspectj/rocks
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/aspectj/rocks/Hello.java
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/aspectj/rocks/Hello_Roo_JpaActiveRecord.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/aspectj/rocks/Hello_Roo_JpaEntity.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/aspectj/rocks/Hello_Roo_ToString.aj
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/aspectj/rocks/Hello_Roo_Configurable.aj
```

Look more details at [spring roo docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/architecture.html)

I want to use my IDE (IDEA) for debugging code in *.aj. IDEA allow to set breakpoint inside *.aj file, but cannot handle it.

It is possible to debug *.aj files with current level of support from IDE?

Comment: i know that the aspectj compiler places debug information in the class files it generates. if your using the community edition of IDEA, it doesnt support those features, but the full version or eclipse will.

Comment: I created FR at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116518

Comment: ohhh! spring roo, now i dont know what the hell that does. but plain aspectj works without a problem.